Improving Text Alignment in OCR-Extracted Text Using pytesseract
I'm facing issues with misaligned text extraction from images. I suspect the problem lies in formatting rather than extraction. Can I utilize bounding box coordinates to improve text alignment?
see this is the original image where the price of column is starting from the same point

Here is the code:
def extract_text(self, image):
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    text_regions = []
    retval, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(gray_image)

    section_groups = {}
    section_threshold = 20
    for i in range(1, retval):
        x, y, w, h, area = stats[i]
    section_groups.setdefault(y // section_threshold, []).append((x, y, w, h))

    for section_key, components in section_groups.items():
        section_image = gray_image[components[0][1]:components[-1][1] + components[-1][3],
                        :]
        extracted_text, section_boxes = self._extract_text_and_boxes(section_image)
        text_regions.append((extracted_text, section_boxes))

    return text_regions

def _extract_text_and_boxes(self, component):
    extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(component, config=self.config)
    boxes = self.get_text_boxes(component)
    return extracted_text, boxes

def get_text_boxes(self, image):
    results = pytesseract.image_to_data(image, output_type=Output.DICT)
    boxes = []
    for i in range(0, len(results["text"])):
        x = results["left"][i]
        y = results["top"][i]
        w = results["width"][i]
        h = results["height"][i]

        text = results["text"][i]
        conf = float(results["conf"][i])
        if conf > 0:
            boxes.append((x, y, w, h))

    return boxes


hey and welcome to stackoverflow, please supply some code and the image you want to correct. It is not possible to give you accurate suggestions without seeing your image

You can check my answer here if it might apply to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78339097/16815358

I'm encountering an issue where the extracted text appears misaligned, and I suspect it's related to the formatting rather than the extraction process itself. I'm working with general types of images, not a specific one. I'm wondering if I can use the bounding box coordinates of the detected text to improve the alignment when printing the text. Any insights or suggestions on how to utilize the bounding box coordinates for better text alignment would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Please see this and improve your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@code_comm alignment looks good, can you also include an image to explain what do you mean by misaligned?

Are you complaining because the COLUMNS aren't aligned?  If so, you are expecting FAR too much from these tools.  Surely you can see it would be trivial to reformat this to look however you want.
